# Is my code right to use batch normalization layers in tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, batch-normalization

I have two inputs: `qi_pos & qi_neg` with the same shape. They should be processed by the two mlp layers, and finally get two results which acts as score. Here is my codes:

```
  self.mlp1_pos  =    nn_layers.full_connect_(qi_pos,        256, activation='relu', use_bn = None, keep_prob=self.keep_prob,  name = 'deep_mlp_1')
  self.mlp2_pos  =    nn_layers.full_connect_(self.mlp1_pos, 128,  activation='relu', use_bn = True, keep_prob=self.keep_prob,  name = 'deep_mlp_2')
  self.pos_pair_sim = nn_layers.full_connect_(self.mlp2_pos,  1,  activation=None, use_bn = True, keep_prob=self.keep_prob,  name = 'deep_mlp_3')
  tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
  self.mlp1_neg  =    nn_layers.full_connect_(qi_neg,        256, activation='relu', use_bn = None, keep_prob=self.keep_prob,  name = 'deep_mlp_1')
  self.mlp2_neg  =    nn_layers.full_connect_(self.mlp1_neg, 128,  activation='relu', use_bn = True, keep_prob=self.keep_prob,  name = 'deep_mlp_2')
  self.neg_pair_sim = nn_layers.full_connect_(self.mlp2_neg,  1,  activation=None, use_bn = True, keep_prob=self.keep_prob,  name = 'deep_mlp_3')
```

I use BN layer to normalize the nodes in hidden layers:

```
def full_connect_(inputs, num_units, activation=None, use_bn = None, keep_prob = 1.0, name='full_connect_'):
  with tf.variable_scope(name):
    shape = [inputs.get_shape()[-1], num_units]
    weight = weight_variable(shape)
    bias = bias_variable(shape[-1])
    outputs_ = tf.matmul(inputs, weight) + bias
    if use_bn:
        outputs_ = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(outputs_, center=True, scale=True, is_training=True,decay=0.9,epsilon=1e-5, scope='bn')
    if activation=="relu":
      outputs = tf.nn.relu(outputs_)
    elif activation == "tanh":
      outputs = tf.tanh(outputs_)
    elif activation == "sigmoid":
      outputs = tf.nn.sigmoid(outputs_)
    else:
      outputs = outputs_
    return  outputs

   with tf.name_scope('predictions'):
      self.sim_diff = self.pos_pair_sim - self.neg_pair_sim # shape = (batch_size, 1)
      self.preds = tf.sigmoid(self.sim_diff) # shape = (batch_size, 1)
      self.infers = self.pos_pair_sim
```

Below is the loss definition.It seems all right.

```
with tf.name_scope('predictions'):
  sim_diff = pos_pair_sim - neg_pair_sim
  predictions = tf.sigmoid(sim_diff)
  self.infers = pos_pair_sim
## loss and optim
with tf.name_scope('loss'):
  self.loss = nn_layers.cross_entropy_loss_with_reg(self.labels, self.preds)
  tf.summary.scalar('loss', self.loss)
```

I am not sure whether I have used the BN layers in right way. I mean that the BN parameters are derived from the hidden units from the two separate parts, which are based on `qi_pos` and `qi_neg` tensors as inputs. Anyway,  anyone could help check it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine to me, there's no problem in applying BN in different branches of the network. But I'd like to mention few notes here:

- BN hyperparameters are pretty standard, so I usually don't manually set `decay`, `epsilon` and `renorm_decay`. It doesn't mean you mustn't change them, it's simply unnecessary in most cases.
- You're applying the BN *before* the activation function, however, there is evidence that it works better if applied *after* the activation. See, for example, [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47143521/712995). Once again, it doesn't mean it's a bug, simply one more architecture to consider.

Comment: Thanks.  By the way, is it necessary to use BN in my network ?  Actually my network only has three layers and the inputs are embedings of short sentence. I hear that BN is common used in the computer version network since the network's parameters are very large and dense.

Comment: That's a deep question, there's no universal answer to it. BN *can* make worse, in terms of speed of convergence (typically, RNN and RL tasks). It's also possible that data is so well normalized that BN doesn't make a big difference, however not free in terms of computations. If there're only 3 layers and data is well pre-processed, I'd generally consider one or none BN, then move on with examining my model. It might end up with several BN, but not the design I'd start with.