# i-RevNet on keras on MNIST dataset

Tags: python, keras

I want to implement i-RevNet on MNIST dataset on keras and generate the original 28*28 input images from the output of i-RevNet, but i don't have a clue. Online resources I can find are all based on tensorflow.

Answer (score 1):

important is this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.07088.pdf - *i-REVNET: DEEP INVERTIBLE NETWORKS* and this git https://github.com/jhjacobsen/pytorch-i-revnet

when reading the above paper critical components in i-RevNets are **homeomorphic layers**, on the link between topology and neural nets  cf http://colah.github.io/posts/2014-03-NN-Manifolds-Topology/ - **Neural Networks, Manifolds, and Topology** ( search for 'homeomorphic' )

in https://github.com/jhjacobsen/pytorch-i-revnet homeomorphic layers are implemented in `class irevnet_block(nn.Module)`, note that there are **NO** operations that discard information like **maxpooling, averaging, ...** ( with exception of the output layer ), only *batch normalization* ( https://towardsdatascience.com/batch-normalization-in-neural-networks-1ac91516821c ) is applied, the ReLUs are also locally strictly linear.

in [Where do I call the BatchNormalization function in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716454/where-do-i-call-the-batchnormalization-function-in-keras) is how to implement this in keras, simply stack the layers into a homeomorphic layer:

```
homeomorphic layer -> NO POOLING, ... LAYERS
model.add(Dense(64, init='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
```

the rest of the code in https://github.com/jhjacobsen/pytorch-i-revnet/blob/master/models/iRevNet.py like i.e. `def inverse(self, x)` or `def forward(self, x)` can be reproduced using the keras functions in https://keras.io/layers/merge/ . Cf https://github.com/jhjacobsen/pytorch-i-revnet/blob/master/models/model_utils.py on the `merge` and `split` functions, they use `torch.cat` and `torch.split` whichs keras equivalents are in https://keras.io/layers/merge/