# Convolutional Autoencoders

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

**I am writing a code for running autoencoder on CIFAR10 dataset and see the reconstructed images.**

The requirement is to create

**Encoder** with First Layer

- Input shape: (32,32,3)
- Conv2D Layer with 64 Filters of (3,3)
- BatchNormalization layer
- ReLu activation
- 2D MaxpoolingLayer with (2,2) filter

**Encoder** with Second Layer

- Conv2D layer with 16 filters (3,3)
- BatchNormalization layer
- ReLu activation
- 2D MaxpoolingLayer with (2,2) filter
- Final Encoded as MaxPool with (2,2) with all previous layers

---

**Decoder** with First Layer

- Input shape: encoder output
- Conv2D Layer with 16 Filters of (3,3)
- BatchNormalization layer
- ReLu activation
- UpSampling2D with (2,2) filter

**Decoder** with Second Layer

- Conv2D Layer with 32 Filters of (3,3)
- BatchNormalization layer
- ReLu activation
- UpSampling2D with (2,2) filter
- Final Decoded as Sigmoid with all previous layers

---

I understand that

1. When we are creating Convolutional Autoencoder (or any AE), we need to pass the output of the previous layer to the next layer.
2. So, when I create the first Conv2D layer with ReLu and then perform BatchNormalization .. in which I pass the Conv2D layer .. right?
3. But when I do MaxPooling2D .. what should I pass .. BatchNormalization output or Conv2D layer output?

**Also, is there any order in which I should be performing these operations?**

- Conv2D --> BatchNormalization --> MaxPooling2D
- OR
- Conv2D --> MaxPooling2D --> BatchNormalization

---

I am attaching my code below ... I have attempted it to two different ways and hence getting different outputs (in terms of model summary and also model training graph)

Can someone please help me by explaining which is the correct method (Method-1 or Method-2)? Also, how do I understand which graph shows better model performance?

**Method - 1**

```
input_image = Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))

### Encoder
conv1_1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_image)
bnorm1_1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1_1)
mpool1_1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(conv1_1)

conv1_2 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(mpool1_1)
borm1_2 = BatchNormalization()(conv1_2)

encoder = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(conv1_2)

### Decoder
conv2_1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoder)
bnorm2_1 = BatchNormalization()(conv2_1)
up1_1 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(conv2_1)

conv2_2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up1_1)
bnorm2_2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2_2)
up2_1 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(conv2_2)

decoder = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(up2_1)

model = Model(input_image, decoder)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
model.summary()

history = model.fit(trainX, trainX, 
                    epochs=50, 
                    batch_size=1000, 
                    shuffle=True,
                    verbose=2,
                    validation_data=(testX, testX)
                    )
```

As an output of the model summary, I get this

> Total params: 18,851
>
> Trainable params: 18,851
>
> Non-trainable params: 0

```
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

[image: Model Loss Graph - 1]

---

**Method - 2**

```
input_image = Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))

### Encoder
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_image)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)

encoder = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

### Decoder

x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoder)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)

decoder = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

model = Model(input_image, decoder)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
model.summary()

history = model.fit(trainX, trainX, 
                        epochs=50, 
                        batch_size=1000, 
                        shuffle=True,
                        verbose=2,
                        validation_data=(testX, testX)
                        )
```

As an output of the model summary, I get this

> Total params: 19,363
>
> Trainable params: 19,107
>
> Non-trainable params: 256

```
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

[image: Model Loss Graph - 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In method 1, BatchNormalization layers does not exist in the compiled model, as the output of these layers are not used anywhere. You can check this by running `model1.summary()`

Method 2 is perfectly alright.

Order of the operations :
Conv2D --> BatchNormalization --> MaxPooling2D  is usually the common approach.
Though either order would work since, since BatchNorm is just mean and variance normalization.

**Edit:**

For Conv2D --> BatchNormalization --> MaxPooling2D :

`conv1_1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_image)
bnorm1_1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1_1)
mpool1_1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(bnorm1_1)`
and then use mpool1_1 as input for next layer.

For Conv2D --> MaxPooling2D --> BatchNormalization:

`conv1_1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_image) 
mpool1_1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(conv1_1)
bnorm1_1 = BatchNormalization()(mpool1_1)`
and then use bnorm1_1 as input for next layer.

Comment: What changes should I make in Method-1 in order to utilize the BatchNormalization? The reason I ask is that I want to understand and visualize, how the input of the previous layer is passed to the following layer.

Comment: I have edited the answer accordingly. For method-1, follow For Conv2D --> MaxPooling2D --> BatchNormalization code for all parts as applicable.

Comment: To visualize, use `model.summary()`. This would give all the details about each layer and their connections. Hope the answer gets accepted.

Answer (score 0):

To effectively use BatchNormalization layer, you should always use it before activation.

Instead of:

```
conv1_1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_image)
bnorm1_1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1_1)
mpool1_1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(bnorm1_1)
```

Use it like this:

```
conv1_1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same')(input_image)
bnorm1_1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1_1)
act_1 = Activation('relu')(bnorm1_1)
mpool1_1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(act_1)
```

For more details, check here:
[Where do I call the BatchNormalization function in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716454/where-do-i-call-the-batchnormalization-function-in-keras)